# are values in app.config safe?

Tags: c#, app-config

Maybe a bit of stupid question but I want to know if values that I put in the app.config for use in my application are safe? I am going to use this in an application in C#. I need it to be safe against reverse engineering or other ways of getting that key so people could read my password.

I want to encrypt and decrypt passwords and I need a key for that. Is it safe to put the key in the app.config file?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SecurityKey" value="secKey" />
  </appSettings>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the web: yes very secure. From the server: as vulnerable as any file.

Comment: Safe against who? Where are you deploying?

Comment: I am using this as a desktop application in C#. So I need it to be safe against reverse engineering

Answer (score 0):

Safe from whom, and doing what? I presume you mean from a hacker accessing the machine's filesystem and acquiring the encryption key.

There is a mitigation for this - [encrypted configuration sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky(v=vs.140).aspx) which are intended for the purpose of storing passphrases and other sensitive information. I can't give much advice on this since I've never used them.

One thing I will add is that the way your question is phrased *implies* that you're devising your own security mechanism. Unless you are an **expert** in this field I would strongly advise against that, as rolling your own security is very difficult and quite easy to introduce non-obvious but critical security holes. I would strongly suggest looking into out-of-the-box identity management supplied with the .Net framework rather than writing your own.

Comment: You are right, I am not an expert. I am not using my own encrypter but I use the TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider. I am just starting out with Encryption so I need to learn a lot.

Comment: Encryption algorithms are one thing and much credit to you if you're really brainy enough to devise one of those; but what you use them for is also important. If all you want to do is give a user a login with a password then [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) is probably the way to go - I presume this is suitable for you as you mention using a web.config which implies an ASP.NET site. By all means do whatever you like for learning, but *please* use an out-of-the-box solution if you're going to be handling real users' data.

Comment: I am making an C# desktop application and I am going to use a password for connecting with a server. Therefore I need this password to be safe. I can not interact with the server in any way because it is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially unsafe, if you don't trust your network admins. It would be worth trying [DPAPI](http://www.obviex.com/samples/dpapi.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe, you should encrypt the value of the safeKey. You can use [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx) for that.

> The DPAPI protected configuration provider supports machine-level and
>   user-level stores for key storage. The choice of store depends largely
>   on whether or not your application shares a server with other
>   applications and whether or not sensitive data must be kept private
>   for each application. Note that if your application is deployed in a
>   Web farm, you should use the RSA protected configuration provider due
>   to the ease with which RSA keys can be exported.